# Is it possible to filter and modify the contents of a Javascript array in one go?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

As the title states, I am wondering if it is possible to filter and array and then modify the values in one go? However, this is better explained with an example.

Imagine I have an array of numbers and I want to filter that array to include only positive numbers, then do some sort of calculation on the remaining numbers, say multiply by 10. Do I have to filter the array and then do an iteration to modify the values or can I do something like this?

```
const ages = [-243, -132, 112, 40, -96];
const filtered = ages.filter((number => (number > 0)) * 10);
```

Comment: _"on the remaining numbers"_ - doing the modification in the filter will do it to all numbers. Filter also expects a boolean return value, so even if you did the modification I'm not sure it would affect the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.. I would do:

```js
const ages = [-243, -132, 112, 40, -96];
const filtered = ages.filter(number => number > 0).map(x => x * 10);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for, I will mark your answer as accepted when the timer expires.

Comment: You CAN filter and modify using the filter command without using `map` though: see [this section in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#affecting_initial_array_modifying_appending_and_deleting).  The advantage would be not looping through the array twice.  Obviously it makes almost no difference with such a small array so the accepted answer is cleaner.

Comment: You don't need to filter and then map, instead use reduce and do all stuff in single function

Answer (score 3):

You do this with single [reduce](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj6x76Nn-zwAhUk8XMBHa68BPwQFjAAegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce&usg=AOvVaw1rZ36_gx-fT2lgEYKcfeI5) function

```js
const ages = [-243, -132, 112, 40, -96];

const result = ages.reduce((arr, num) => {
  if (num > 0) arr.push(num * 10);
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

or with single line function using [flatMap](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiOkNu9oezwAhW573MBHU3EA3gQFjAAegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FflatMap&usg=AOvVaw2LDH1XOMaqnFVsrlBqNm4a)

```js
const ages = [-243, -132, 112, 40, -96];

const result = ages.flatMap((num) => (num > 0 ? [num * 10] : []));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **Yes, you can**.

1. You can filter and modify the array in only one go.

```js
  console.log(
  [243 * 10, -132, 112, 40, -96]
  .filter((age, index, arr) => { 
         arr[index+1] *= 10;
         return age > 0;
 }))
```

2. But I think we should avoid it as much as we can. Because it mutates the original array.